# Graphic artifacts / Glitchy appearance around border of browsers - Windows 10 Home

Tags: drivers, browser, visual-artifacts

So recently my laptop has randomly on rare occasions decide to glitch out around the borders of browsers, notably, when using internet browsers. I have an example in the screenshot attached. The problem is only around the border of windows and internet browsers but the contents inside the browser is just fine. I'm not sure what is causing the issue and I have tried to change the screen resolution and revert back, as other users have described when I researched this problem, in order to refresh the screen but the glitching is still there. The only thing I have found to remove it is restarting the laptop. I get the feeling that this might be a software issue maybe since this started notably after I installed the most recent nvidia driver (445.75).

I mainly use Firefox 74.0(32-bit) when this issue occured. Not sure if the web browser is part of the cause since this issue affects the borders of all my windows and web browsers.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as this occurrence worries me.

[Example of the browser border visual glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvyMB.png)

Comment: If you rollback your display drivers does it solve the problem.  Instead of replying with a comment you should edit your question to include this vital information

Comment: I went to try that but I am unable to rollback because the option to rollback the driver was greyed out.

Comment: So uninstall the version you have installed, and download an earlier version, and then edit your question indicating if that solves your problem

Comment: I'll try that. I wasn't sure about uninstalling the driver since I've never done that before and was a bit scared.

Answer (score 0):

I am/was having this identical issue on my external monitor that I hooked my laptop up to. I did notice that the color profile was blank in my display settings when before it said it was Lenovo thinkpad LCD monitor profile, however it was blank for some reason.

I used DDU https://www.wagnardsoft.com/. download, extract, then go ahead and reboot windows in safe mode. Go into safe mode using the following if you don't already know:

Click the Windows-button → Power.
Hold down the shift key and click Restart.
Click the option Troubleshoot and then Advanced options.
Go to “Advanced options” and click Start-up Settings.
Under “Start-up Settings” click Restart.
Various boot options are displayed. ...
Windows 10 starts in Safe Mode.

then run DDU. There will be an initial screen of options. Only thing I check extra is the PhysX removal, Leave all others default. then run the recommend remove and reboot.

After it reboots immediately reinstall Geforce experience with the latest drivers (don't go to windows update because it will likely try to pull some crap generic nvidia drivers).

The should be good. Also keep in mind this will also take off your monitor drivers (if your monitor has drivers, otherwise the system will use generic LCD. Let me know how it goes.

The specs I had the issues with:

Laptop -Lenovo, Legion Y740 1080p 144 hrtz monitor attached

GPU - Nvidia 2080 Max-Q

External Monitor - Omen x27 240 hrtz

Windows 10 latest updates